# jquery click event for child div not working in plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, onclick

I'm trying to add a click event on each row. On click I need to be able to grab the name (ex. Jeremy) and place in the top div, replacing the question marks. My click event only works on id="data" but not the child divs. I have my code here on codepen as well http://codepen.io/rrschweitzer/pen/GrRyLg?editors=0110. Any help is much appreciated!!

This is my html:

```
<div id="interview-test">
  <div class="top-bars">
    <div id="secret">???</div>
    <button id="clear">Clear</button>
  </div>
  <div id="data"></div> 
</div>
```

This is my Jquery:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.interviewTest = function() {
  var self = this;
  var testData = null;
  var url = "https://private-f3b4b-interview2.apiary-mock.com/data";

// create rows
self.createRow = function(data) {
  var theRow = $('<div>').addClass('rows')
   .append($('<div>').addClass('image-container')
      .append($('<img>').addClass('picture').attr('src', data.image)))
   .append($('<div>').addClass('name').append($('<h1>').html(data.name)))
   .append(self.getDate(data.timestamp))
  return theRow;
}

self.getDate = function(date) {
  var date = date.slice(0,-3)
  var newdate = new Date(date * 1000)
  var year = newdate.getFullYear();
  var month = newdate.getMonth();
  var day = newdate.getDay()
  var formattedDate = month + '/' + day + '/' + year
  return formattedDate;
}
// api call
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ');
    },
    url: url,
    success: function(data, status) {
      var dataObject = data;
      var i = 0;
      var testData = [];

      for(var key in dataObject) {
        testData[i] = dataObject[key]
        i++;
      }
      // console.log(testData);
      self.createDataList(testData, i);
    }
})

self.createDataList = function(data, size) {
  var rows = $(self).find('#data');
  if (size != 0) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      // console.log(value)
      rows.append(self.createRow(value))
    })
  }
}

 // event listeners
 $(self).find('.rows').on('click', function(e) {
    var current = $(e.currentTarget);
    console.log(current);
    // if(current)
 })
}}(jQuery))$('#interview-test').interviewTest();
```

Comment: There's an error somewhere in your codepen code.

Comment: Is the snippet supposed to show "??? clear"?: https://jsfiddle.net/v6b9mL6x/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your event listeners after elements (rows) are created:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.interviewTest = function() {
  var self = this;
  var testData = null;
  var url = "https://private-f3b4b-interview2.apiary-mock.com/data";

// create rows
self.createRow = function(data) {
  var theRow = $('<div>').addClass('rows')
   .append($('<div>').addClass('image-container')
      .append($('<img>').addClass('picture').attr('src', data.image)))
   .append($('<div>').addClass('name').append($('<h1>').html(data.name)))
   .append(self.getDate(data.timestamp))
  return theRow;
}

self.getDate = function(date) {
  var date = date.slice(0,-3)
  var newdate = new Date(date * 1000)
  var year = newdate.getFullYear();
  var month = newdate.getMonth();
  var day = newdate.getDay()
  var formattedDate = month + '/' + day + '/' + year
  return formattedDate;
}
// api call
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ');
    },
    url: url,
    success: function(data, status) {
      var dataObject = data;
      var i = 0;
      var testData = [];

      for(var key in dataObject) {
        testData[i] = dataObject[key]
        i++;
      }
      // console.log(testData);
      self.createDataList(testData, i);
    }
})

self.createDataList = function(data, size) {
  var rows = $(self).find('#data');
  if (size != 0) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      // console.log(value)
      rows.append(self.createRow(value))
    });

    self.addEventListeners()
  }
}

self.addEventListeners() {
  // event listeners
  $(self).find('.rows').on('click', function(e) {
    var current = $(e.currentTarget);
    console.log(current);
    // if(current)
  })
}
}}(jQuery))$('#interview-test').interviewTest();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use event delegation for this to attach the event with the parent element which will fire for all the matching selector child elements.

```
$(self).on('click', ".rows",function(e) {
        var current = $(this);
        if(current)
        {
           var name = current.find(".name").text();
           $("#secret").text(name);
        }
    })
```

code pen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZxRwM?editors=0110

Answer (score 0):

Your demo doesn't work however looking at your code you are trying to look for `self.find('.rows')` before the ajax has completed and the rows have been created

You either need to delegate the event or wait until rows are added in the ajax success